# Localhost issue with flask-http auth

Tags: python, xampp, flask-httpauth

I have the following:

```
@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username_or_token, password):
    logger = logging.getLogger('__name__')
    logger.error('username = %s' %username_or_token)
    # first try to authenticate by token    
    user = USER.verify_auth_token(username_or_token)
    if not user:
        with contextlib.closing(DBSession()) as session:                                                                                                                    
            try:
                # try to authenticate with username/password
                user = session.query(USER).filter_by(USERSEMAIL = username_or_token).first()
                if not user or not user.verify_password(password):
                    return False
            except exc.SQLAlchemyError, error:
                session.rollback()
                raise_database_error(error)       
    g.user = user
    return True



@app.route('/api/token')
@auth.login_required
def get_auth_token():
    token = g.user.generate_auth_token()
    return jsonify({ 'token': token.decode('ascii') })
```

When I access the `api/token` route using `localhost`, I am prompted to enter my `username` and `password`. Afterwards when I check my log, I find that the `username_or_token` variable is `''`.

The strange this is I have tested the exact same code on my `online server` and had no issues..

I am using `Advanced Rest Client`. When using this `plugin`, I add an `Authorisation header` and use the drop down fields `Login` and `Password` under the `Basic` tab. I have been doing the same when executing on my `online server`.

I am using `XAMPP`. Not really too sure what other info to provide.

Has anyone ever experienced this before?

**Request Details**

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Basic Z2lyaTFAZ21haWwuY29tOmFzZA==
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4
```

**HTTPIE Output**

[image]
[image]

Once again the `username` is set to `''`.

Comment: The username is set to `''` when there is no Authorization header in the request, basically this is the mechanism that can allow access to anonymous users. Can you verify that there was an Authorization header in the request and what was the value in it?

Comment: I'm going to make a guess here. I'm not sure, but I suspect there is an issue with CORS that is interfering. Could you try to send a request from a different client? For example, you can use httpie from the command line (`pip install httpie`, then `http --auth user:pass GET http://url`).

Comment: I tried your method and also tried `REST Client for Android` on my mobile but unfortunately have the same problem...

Comment: I don't know if the REST client for Android is browser based or not. Can you try httpie as I suggested? That ensures there are no browser related troubles such as the CORS limitations. Send your request with httpie then add the output to your question.

Comment: Thanks. You did say you are using XMPP, but I did not realize that means you are using Apache as reverse proxy. So I'm going to ask you two more things. Please add the apache configuration, and also check if you can  authenticate if you run your server without a reverse proxy. You can use gunicorn or uwsgi. I'm wondering if Apache is consuming the authentication information and not passing it through to the Python app.